# Can I save a .txt file passed as a command line argument to a char array in C?

Tags: c, text, arguments

I'd like to save a .txt file that I am passing as an argument into some sort of datatype. For example, if my command was ./projexec -c "some text" filename.txt, my goal is to copy the contents of filename.txt(argv[3]) into a char array. Is this possible, if so how?

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
int i;
FILE *fp;
char txtfile[];

for(i=0; i<argc; i++) {
    if(argc>1 && argv[3] !=NULL) {
        fp=fopen(argv[3],"r");
    }
    else {
        printf("There is no .txt file in this argument.");
    }

}
```

UPDATE: fread did the trick!

```
#define size 1000 
int main(int argc, char  *argv []) {

int i;
FILE *fp;
char argtxt[]= ".txt";
char txtfile[size];
size_t br;

for(i=0; i<argc; i++){

if(argc > 1 && strstr(argv[i],argtxt)!=NULL){
fp=fopen(argv[i],"r");
br=fread(txtfile,sizeof(txtfile),size, fp);
printf("file copied.\n");
}
}
printf(txtfile);

}
```

Comment: Yes, by using `fread` to read the whole file (after you find out its size). Or, you can `fread` it in chunks into an allocated buffer without first knowing the file size, reallocating the buffer as necessary as you proceed, until no more can be read.

Comment: use: `if(argc>=3`

Comment: Why have it in a loop? The file will be attempted be opened more than once, with unpredictable results. Remove the loop.

Comment: `fread(txtfile,sizeof(txtfile),size, fp);` is incorrect. You either need `fread(txtfile, sizeof txtfile, 1, fp);` or `fread(txtfile, 1, sizeof txtfile, fp);` but the second is better because `fread` will tell you *how many* bytes were read, which will affect your subsequent search in the otherwise uninitialised buffer.

Comment: Why is it incorrect? The .txt file still copied and printed.

Comment: Becaue you are telling `fread` to read `size * size` bytes if available and if the file is larger than `size` you will break the array. Please read my previous comment carefully and the man page about `fread` parameters.

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend reading about the "**mmap**" system call.
You need to open a file using the "**open**" system call,
then call "**mmap**" on it, which returns a pointer to a buffer (created for you by the system) so you can just treat it like a very long string.

Lines are separated with "\n" and make sure you have opened the file with writing permissions if you are planning on using "**strtok**" on the string.
This is due to the fact that "**strtok**" rewrites the delimiter to a null terminator.